# jquery datatables scroll to top when pages clicked from bottom

Tags: datatables

I am using a jQuery datatable with bottom pagination. When the pages are clicked from bottom , I want it to scroll it to top, so users do not have to manually do that for longer pages. I tried using dataTables_scrollBody, but it doesn't work properly

Here is my code:

```js
oTable = $('#tTable').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function(o) {
        $('dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop(0);
     }
});
```

The page scrolls to top only when you click first/last (which I think is default behaviour), but not with every page click.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update**. The original answer was targeting 1.9.x. In dataTables 1.10.x it is much easier :

```js
table.on('page.dt', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wq853akd/**

Also, if you're using the bootstrap version of datatables, you may notice that when using the fix, the page actually scrolls back down after scrolling to the top. This is because it is focusing on the clicked button as per [this datatables.net thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33724/scroll-top-on-data-load-bootstrap-issue). You can fix this by simply focusing on the table header after the animate call, like so:

```
table.on('page.dt', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
  }, 'slow');

  $('thead tr th:first-child').focus().blur();
});
```

---

### **Original Answer**

You should target `.dataTables_wrapper` and attach the event to `.paginate_button` instead. Here with a nice little animation :

```js
function paginateScroll() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
    }, 100);
    console.log('pagination button clicked'); //remove after test
    $(".paginate_button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
    $(".paginate_button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/EjbEJ/**

Comment: thanks, this works most of the time, but when you click page1, page2, it scrolls, but with page3, it doesn't scroll, it has random behaviour. The page scrolls for 2-3 clicks and then halts after that.

Comment: @user2675939, Oh YES - you are absolutely right!! Didnt think of that. This is because dataTables recreate some of the buttons and by that reset the events each time you paginate. Example : It goes well if you just go forward, but backwards the events is resetted since dataTables must change the behaviour of those buttons (active and so on). The solution is to unbind / bind the event to all the paginate_buttons each time the event itself is triggered. Please see the update above and the updated fiddle. This defently works.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. However, this scrolls to the top of the table, if you want to scroll to the top of the page (in my case a sticky header was covering part of the table) use `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");`

Comment: Consider `$(".paginate_button:not(.disabled)")` to avoid scrolling when clicked on a disabled next/prev button.

Comment: I used above code. When I click the paginate button, scroll go to top, But after load data, back to bottom of page. Why?

Answer (score 14):

Since Datatables 1.10 there is this page event
https://datatables.net/reference/event/page

So one can use

```
$('#example_table').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300);
} );
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mcyhqrdx/

Comment: Your answer was the best.

Answer (score 2):

This worked out for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldStart = 0;
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnDrawCallback": function (o) {
            if ( o._iDisplayStart != oldStart ) {
                var targetOffset = $('#example').offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
                oldStart = o._iDisplayStart;
            }
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using datatables and Allan's solution ([found here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/158/autoscroll-to-top)) worked perfectly for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldStart = 0;
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnDrawCallback": function (o) {
        if ( o._iDisplayStart != oldStart ) {
            var targetOffset = $('#example').offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
            oldStart = o._iDisplayStart;
        }
      }
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank's from davidkonrad. But when I used his code, after I clicked on paginate button, scroll of page went to top and then after load data, scroll backed to bottom.

I combined multiple posts in StackOverFlow and Datatables forum.

I defined a global variable :

```
var isScroll = false
```

When it's clicked on paginate button `isScroll` set to `true`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.paginate_button:not(.disabled)', function () {
    isScroll = true;
});
```

And finally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        ...
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            if (isScroll) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
                }, 500);
                isScroll = false;
            }
        },
        ...
    });
});
```

Thanks from @0110

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. Here's my solution.

```
$("#divContainingTheDataTable").click(function(event){
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("paginate_button")) {
        $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#divContainingTheDataTable").offset().top
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

I tried targetting .paginate_button but it never seemed to fire. My approach checks the div containing the datatable, if you click on the pagination buttons, the page scrolls up to the top of the container.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using the bootstrap version of Datatables:**

You may notice that when using the fix from the accepted answer above, the page actually scrolls back down to the paging controls after scrolling to the top. This is because it is focusing on the clicked paging button as per [this datatables.net thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33724/scroll-top-on-data-load-bootstrap-issue). You can fix this by simply focusing on the table header after the animate call like so:

```
table.on('page.dt', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
    }, 'slow');

    $('thead tr th:first-child').focus().blur();
});
```

Note: the chained `blur()`'ing is done so that you the user doesn't see any focused styles on `th:first-child`.