# jquery datatables scroll to top when pages clicked from bottom forward to backward randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable and i want to change it's default behaviour. Right now when I click to page no e.g 61, page-scroll remains at bottom. But when I click page from 61 to 60 page scroll comes at middle of the page. I want to keep all the pages to be scrolled at bottom of page regardless of random page click at bottom from first to last or random page click. I have also taken the reference from this link:
[jquery datatables scroll to top when pages clicked from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609257/jquery-datatables-scroll-to-top-when-pages-clicked-from-bottom)
but this is for making scroll on top by default.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Angular?

Comment: no jquery datatable.

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jb0e6whr/ this is code i am using for dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

You should target `.dataTables_wrapper` and attach the event to `.paginate_button` instead. Here with a nice little animation :

```js
function paginateScroll() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 100);
    console.log('pagination button clicked'); //remove after test
    $(".paginate_button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
    $(".paginate_button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();
```

Here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjbEJ/85/)

Disclaimer: I've just made a minor edit in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609257/jquery-datatables-scroll-to-top-when-pages-clicked-from-bottom) whose link has been posted in the question itself. `scrollTop: $(document).height()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for this but this not worked . also tried within document.ready.

Comment: @amarghodke Oh. Can you please post your code or else a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jb0e6whr/ this is jquery datatable for dynamic data so you will not see any of records.

Comment: @amarghodke Where have you added the above code ie. to scroll to top pages when navigating b/w pages?

Comment: Can you please join [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131678/jquery-datatable-scroll-to-top-issue). It's better than having an extended discussion by commenting.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening between second last and last page pagination eg. 60 and 61.when we navigate to the last page and if the number of records are less than the pagination size, then the UI shifts as the datatable adjusts it's height. The issue may be seen when the page is moved from last page to 2nd last page or any other page. So this is a natural behavior and not an issue