# How to scroll to first row during pagination in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, datatables

I am new to DataTables and i am using it in order to display the contents which I am getting from the database.

I am not able to scroll to the top of the page or to the first row when I click on pagination buttons from the bottom of the page.

```
$.ajax({
contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
type: "GET",
url: "xyz",
data: dataString,
async: "false",
datatype: "json",
success: function(response) {

       writeResultTable();
       var obj = parseJSONfromSearch(response);

       $('#tableId').DataTable( {
            data: obj,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "simple",
        "bServerSide": false,
        "fixedHeader": true,
            columns : [
                       { "targets": [0],
                           "sortable" : true,
                            "render":function(data, type, full, meta){
                               return '<a href="'+full.url+'" target="_blank">' + full.TitlePath + '</a>' + "<br\>" + "<br\>" +                                                                                                                                                                                  full.Description;

                            }}

                   ],
                   "sDom" : '<"top"l<"divline"ip>>rt<"bottom"<"divline"ip>><"clear">',
            "sAutoWidth" : true,
             "fnDrawCallback": function(o) {

                    moveToTop();



          } 
    } );
```

},

```
 error: function(response, status, error ) {
      alert("error123");
      alert(status);
      alert(error);

  }
});

function moveToTop(){
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

I tried several things like below but nothing works: -

```
function paginateScroll() {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
}, 500);
console.log('pagination button clicked');
$(".ui-button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
$(".ui-button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();
```

Comment: Is this what you want?
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609257/jquery-datatables-scroll-to-top-when-pages-clicked-from-bottom

Comment: I tried almost everything given on this page/site but nothing works. I don't know where i am making a mistake. :(

Comment: @ParaBolt, yeah, that answer needs an update. It is targeting dataTables 1.9.x, thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .animate in JQuery with scollTop property and time of scoll in milliseconds as follows

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

function scrollSmooth()
{
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#demo").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}

</script>

<body>

<div id="demo" style="background: pink">ScrollTo This</div>

Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>
Sample Data<br /><br><br><br>

<button onclick="scrollSmooth()">Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried but not working. Just to add i am calling a javascript function inside the fnDrawCallback of Jquery Datatable.                                                                                                 '"fnDrawCallback": function(o) {
             
             moveToTop(); 
             
                     
             }  function moveToTop(){
 
  
   $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#id_2").offset().top
     }, 1000);
}' where id_2 is the div containing the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to hook into the [**`page.dt`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) event. If you have a dataTable :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({}) ;
```

Then you could do this :

```
table.on('page.dt', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wq853akd/**

---

If you explicitly want to scroll to first row, and not just top of the `.dataTables_wrapper`, use this selector instead :

```
scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper tbody tr:eq(0)").offset().top
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wq853akd/1/**

Comment: Hello David,  Yes finally i am able to solve the problem. The way i solved the issue is i called one javascript function from fnDrawCallback                              "fnDrawCallback": function(o) {
                 moveToTop(); 
                             
             }  and inside this function i just get the id of the div containing the table and moved it to top as follows : -                                    var table1 = document.getElementById('content');
     table1.scrollTop =0;

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the first row inside the table body

```
 t.on('page.dt', function() {                       
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow');
 });
```